# insert method on singly linked list, does this work?

Tags: java, list, methods, linked-list, insertion

I am more concern about the insert method that I am working on, a singly linked list that only takes up to 10 nodes. I have a `SinglyLinkedList` that has the `getScore()` method that returns score. I accompanied related methods to see the flow. Basically what I want to accomplish and what I did on the insert method insert the node (which has a score) into the right sorted place from left being the highest score and far right being lowest score. If I have `[100]--[80]--[65]` and another node of score 67 comes along, it becomes `[100]--[80]--[67]--[65]` as long as size is less than 10, `if (size == 10)` then that means list is full and any other node that comes in will only compare it with the last node, for example a new node of 95 compares with only 65, if it's greater than 65 then that means it 95 has to be somewhere in the list, drops the last node '65' and iterate through to find the right place to fit 95. If another node for example higher than 100, say for example 200.. then it would be `[200]--[100]--[95]--[80]--[67]` as long as `size < 10` otherwise kick the least score so the list would still maintain 10 nodes. you get the idea.

```
public void insert(Node n) { 
  //insert if node's score is higher than the last node
  int currScore = n.getScore();
  Node pos = head;

  if(pos.getScore() < currScore) {
    addFirst(n);
  }

  if(pos != null) {
    if(getSize() == 10) {
      if(tail.getScore() < currScore) {
        removeLast();
      } else { 
        n = null;
      }
    } else {
      while(getSize() < 10) {
        if((pos.getNext() != null) && (pos.getNext().getScore() > currScore))
          pos.setNext(pos);
      }
      insertAfter(n,pos);
    }
  }
}

public void addFirst(Node v) {
  if(head == null) {
    head = v;
    tail = v;
    size++;
}

public void insertAfter(Node p, Node v) { //insert v after p
  Node t = p.getNext();
  p.setNext(v);
  v.setNext(t);
  size++;
}

public void removeLast() {
  if(head == null) {
    return;
  }
  Node pos = head;
  if(pos.getNext() == null) {
    pos = null;
  }
  Node curr = head.getNext();
  while(curr.getNext() != null) {
    pos = curr;
    curr.setNext(curr);

    if(curr.getNext() == null) {
      curr = null;
    }
  }         
}

public class Node  {
    private String name;
    private int score;
    private Node next;

    public Node() {
        name = "";
        score = 0;
        next = null;
    }

public Node(String name, int score, Node next) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
    this.next = next;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getScore() {
        return score;
}

public Node getNext() {
        return next;
}
public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}
}

public class SinglyLinkedList {
    public Node head;
    public Node tail;
    public int size;
    static final int MAXSIZE = 10;

public SinglyLinkedList() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}
public void addFirst(Node v) {
    if(head == null) {
    head = v;
    tail = v;
    size++;
    }
}
public void addLast(Node v) {
    v.setNext(null);
    tail.setNext(v);
    tail = v;
    size++;
}
public void insertAfter(Node p, Node v) { //insert v after p
    Node t = p.getNext();
    p.setNext(v);
    v.setNext(t);
    size++;
}
public void removeFirst() {
   if(head == null) {
       return;
   }
   Node t = head;
   head.setNext(head);
   t = null;
   size--;
}
public void removeLast() {
    if(head == null) {
        return;
    }
    Node pos = head;
    if(pos.getNext() == null) {
        pos = null;
    }
    Node curr = head.getNext();
    while(curr.getNext() != null) {
        pos = curr;
        curr.setNext(curr);

        if(curr.getNext() == null) {
            curr = null;
        }
    }         
}

public void insert(Node n) { //insert if node's score is higher than the last node
    int currScore = n.getScore();
    Node pos = head;

    if(pos.getScore() < currScore) {
            addFirst(n);
     }

    if(pos != null) {
        if(getSize() == 10) {
            if(tail.getScore() < currScore) {
                removeLast();
            } else { 
                n = null;
            }
        } else {
            while(getSize() <= 10) {
                if(pos.getNext() != null && pos.getNext().getScore() > currScore)
                pos.setNext(pos);
            }
            insertAfter(n,pos);
        }
    }
}
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}
}
```

Comment: If this is a homework task or data structure exercise than ok. Otherwise I will suggest you to not reinvent the wheel. Use JAVA's collection API.

Comment: Yes, it is homework, just wanted to make sure that method makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your setNext() method??. Are you incrementing the size in setNext() ? .. I think your program will go in an infinite loop because -

```
 while(getSize() < 10) {
                if(pos.getNext() != null && pos.getNext().getScore() > currScore)
                pos.setNext(pos);
            }
```

Where are you doing size++??

Give implementation of all the methods you are using...

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't realize that. Deleted it, but hope you had a chance to take a glimpse before the removal

Comment: Added in the original comment

Comment: Yep... The while loop will go on infinitely... Dont you have to increase the size after you add an element ( pos.setNext(pos);) ??

Comment: on while(getSize() < 10) ? My rationing behind that is .. I don't want to increase size at or after 10 since 10 is the limit. When I add an element, I remove the last or least score to maintain the 10 score

Comment: for example this line if(getSize() == 10) { if(tail.getScore() < currScore){ removeLast(); } says at least to me that if list is full (getSize() == 10) then just check the current node score with the last node score (tail.getScore()) if last node score is less than current node score then removelast()